# How to change just one component on screen using transition/navigation/router in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-router, transition

I have 3 components that I want to show in sequence.

When I click on some button in the first component, change to the next component, and when I click on some button in a second component change to the third component.

I need to change just one bottom component on the main screen, prefer using custom transition (right to left). Is it possible?

Here is an [example](https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053) of what I want to do, but just between components.

Comment: Can you please give an example of your code?

Comment: If you're not changing the screen, only the bottom part of it, perhaps you're not looking for an actual transition, just some animation.